# Disable Pagination based on button

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have tried a few things currently from what I could search online however I, unfortunately, haven't found anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz8Jf.png)

I would like to disable the pagination when I click on the replace button. Since it's loading with a spinner and there is a wait I thought it would make sense to disable it but not remove it. I know how to remove, both on the css side and angularjs. However, in all honesty, I am unsure how to disable this particular feature compared to other works that I have done.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-blue" ng-click="handleLoadAndDeactivate()"
   ng-show="'Load' == importAction && 0 == errors"
   title="Load">
     Replace
</button>
```

AngularJS (Button):

```
$scope.handleLoadAndDeactivate = function () {
      $scope.onCompleteData.targetBody.withDeactivation = true;
      onComplete($scope.onCompleteData, $scope.handleLoadAndDeactivateCompleted);
};
```

AngularJS (Table):

```
$scope.operationsPreloadCompletedTableOptions = new NgTableParams({}, {
    dataset: importLog
});
html
```

Comment: Add `ng-disabled="loading"` to your pagination, and set `$scope.loading = true` on `handleLoadAndDeactivate` and set `$scope.loading = false` on `scope.handleLoadAndDeactivateCompleted`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could achive this:

```js
(function () {
 "use strict";
 const app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("app.AppCtrl", ($scope, $timeout) => {
  $scope.disablePagination = false;
  $scope.handleReplace = () => {
   $scope.disablePagination = true;

   //Your replace logic goes here
   $timeout(() => {
    $scope.disablePagination = false;
   }, 2000);
  };
 }
 );

})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="app.AppCtrl">
  <button ng-disabled="disablePagination">&lt;</button>
  <button ng-disabled="disablePagination">1</button>
  <button ng-disabled="disablePagination">2</button>
  <button ng-disabled="disablePagination">&gt;</button>
  <button ng-click="handleReplace();">Replace</button>
</div>
```